# Returning a Prototype Cell with a Label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I am attempting to connect a label to a prototype cell and return it successfully. I am having some trouble doing so. I have connected my MyCustomTableViewCell. There are officially no "errors" in the app that are detected by xCode. However, when I run it, I am simply getting back a blank table view. Further down in the code (second to last line), I put down "print("Hi!")" to check and see if the code was processing, and the "Hi!" does not show up in the console either when run. Here is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var personText: UILabel!

}



class UserFeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, ComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    private var posts: [PFObject]? {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Query for feeds
        Downloader.sharedDownloader.queryForPosts()

        // Add observers
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "queryFeeds:", name: queryNotification, object: nil)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    // Notification SEL
    func queryFeeds(notification: NSNotification) {
        posts = notification.object as? [PFObject]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "postSegue" {

            let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let composeVc = nav.topViewController as! ComposeViewController
            composeVc.delegate = self

        }
    }
        func dismissComposeViewController(viewController: ComposeViewController) {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }

        func reloadTableViewAfterPosting() {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            Downloader.sharedDownloader.queryForPosts()

        }

    }


    // Mark Table View Data Source
    extension UserFeedTableViewController {

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts?.count ?? 0

    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...

        if let posts = posts {
            let object = posts[indexPath.row]
            cell.personText?.text = object["post"] as? String
            cell.personText?.numberOfLines = 0

        }
        print("Hi!")
        return cell
    }
}
```

How can I alter it so it returns the cell?

Comment: What is the purpose of the extension? Which methods in the class are called?

Comment: Did you try debugging? "Posts" isn't nil?

Comment: Have you set your tableview delegate and datasource?  Why have you implemented those methods in an extension?

Comment: @Paulw11, I have not set tableview delegate & datasource, when I add them to the class and do tableView.delegate = self, and tableView.dataSource. = self, I get a 'redundant conformation' error. As for the extension, the first chunk of the code (the UserFeedTableViewController class) ends after func reloadTableViewAfterPosting(). I'm following a guide currently, but I believe it's to call the class and append to it? And again, thank you to everyone for your help, this is my first time posting on stack overflow, and  all the support is great to see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check `return posts?.count`. Try `return posts?.count ?? 0` to `return 1` to test

Update: I remove my mistake.

Hope this can help.

Comment: I agree with truongky that you need to set your custom UserFeedTableViewController class to conform to the UITableViewDataSource and UiTableViewDelegate classes as he's noted. Modify your code with the code I have put below. It hard codes the number of values in the row to 4 and always returns "Hi!" for the cell row value.

Comment: extension UserFeedTableViewController {
        return 4 // Just a random value
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
        cell.personText?.text = "Hi!"
        print("Hi!")
        return cell
    }
}

Comment: Hey truongky, I tried your changes, and here's the error I end up getting: "Redundant conformance of 'UserFeedTableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'", and same for UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. What happen when you `return 1` instead of `posts?.count`

Comment: This is more of a comment than a post, please review [answer]

Comment: @Truongky, that worked very well! My end goal is to return the count of 'posts' though. If posts?.count ?? 0 does not work, what could do the same thing?

Comment: @Rhdian: I think your `posts?count ?? 0` always return 0. Debug and print its value.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it seems to return just 0. What can I do to make it return the number of posts in the tableview?

Comment: try `return posts?.count`